# java NIO memory map a docker mounted file fail

Tags: java, docker, nio, mount

I recently run into docker and deploy my java application into a tomcat docker container. But I met a very specific error about NIO memory mapping a file:

```
File mark = new File("/location/to/docker/mounted/file");
m_markFile = new RandomAccessFile(mark, "rw");
MappedByteBuffer m_byteBuffer = m_markFile.getChannel().map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 20);
```

And the last function call failed as:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:906)
at com.dianping.cat.message.internal.MessageIdFactory.initialize(MessageIdFactory.java:127)
at com.dianping.cat.message.internal.DefaultMessageManager.initialize(DefaultMessageManager.java:197)
... 34 more
```

I don't know what happened. I tested it in my local Mac environment, it's ok. And within the tomcat docker container, I change the file location to a normal file path, it's ok too. Seems which happens only on docker mounted file.

Other information:

```
root@4520355ed3ac:/usr/local/tomcat# uname -a
Linux 4520355ed3ac 4.4.27-boot2docker #1 SMP Tue Oct 25 19:51:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Mounted a folder in Mac Users to /data

```
root@4520355ed3ac:/usr/local/tomcat# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
none            18745336   6462240  11292372  37% /
tmpfs             509832         0    509832   0% /dev
tmpfs             509832         0    509832   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Users          243924992 150744296  93180696  62% /data
/dev/sda1       18745336   6462240  11292372  37% /etc/hosts
shm                65536         0     65536   0% /dev/shm
```

docker version

```
huanghaideMacBook-Pro:cat huanghai$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
huanghaideMacBook-Pro:cat huanghai$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919
```